# django many to many through forms

Tags: django, forms

I have a many to many relationship, with an intermediate table with extra fields.

I want to create a form that allows me to enter a product, and to be able to choose a price for 1 or more markets.

I can't figure out the views to create this form and print it in a template.

Can you help me?

How the form should look like:
[image]

Relation:

[image]

Models:

```
class Market(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    market = models.ManyToManyField(Market, through='Link')

class Link(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['producto', 'supermercado']]
```

Forms:

```
class MarketForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        fields = ['name']
        model = Market

class ProductForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        fields = ['name']
        model = Product


class LinkForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        fields = ['market','product','link']
        model = Link
```

Answer (score 0):

In the views get the relation data in a JSON format or as a Dictionary object and send it to the frontend, and then use javascript to achieve your desired result.

For eg.

### Link table in db:

| product_id | market_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 11 |
| 1 | 2 | 12 |
| 2 | 2 | 13 |
| 3 | 1 | 14 |
| 4 | 1 | 15 |

### Syntax:

```
dict_obj = [{id:product_id, metadata:{market_id:price}}]
```

### Code:

```
dict_obj =[
    {'1':1, metadata:{1,10}},
    {'2':2, metadata:{1,11}},
    {'3':1, metadata:{2,12}},
    {'4':1, metadata:{2,13}},
    {'5':1, metadata:{1,14}},
    {'6':1, metadata:{1,15}}
]
```

Pass the dictionary object to javascript and manipulate the HTML DOM attributes. If the product_id is 1 and market_id is 2 fetch the price 12 and display it to the user dynamically.

Hope your got your answer